# How to deal with multiple selected checkboxes of the Active Choices Plugin in a script?

Tags: jenkins, checkbox, groovy

Is there a way to use independently the outputs of a checkbox list in the Active Choices plugin on Jenkins ? (as in my example, I need to access to the selected check boxes one at a time

Here are a few screens to explain my problem :

[Active Choices configuration in the job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XRUd.png)

[The script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnO5w.png)

[Checkboxes selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yVqt.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMoKj.png)

I would like to be able to access first to only the Debian_6, then only the Debian 6 32bits :)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As the result is comma-separated, maybe you could split the output:

```sh
# This is a way to split in bash
osArr=(${OS//,/ })

# And then access a result as
os1=${osArr[0]}
```

Or maybe iterate them in a for block

```sh
for os in ${OS//,/ } ; do 
   echo "${os}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the comma separated values into an array and iterate them

```
#!/bin/bash
OS_selected=($(echo $OS | tr "," "\n"))
for values in ${OS_selected[@]}
do
echo $values
done
```